# How do you use object initializers for a list of key value pairs?

Tags: c#, key-value

I can't figure out the syntax to do inline collection initialization for:

```
var a = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize KeyValuePair object the proper way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495165/how-to-initialize-keyvaluepair-object-the-proper-way)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
var a = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A","B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A","B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A","B"),
};
```

Note that you can leave the trailing comma after the last element (probably because .net creators wanted to make automatic code-generation easier), or remove the `()` brackets of the list contructor and the code still compiles.

Comment: You might want to remove that trailing comma

Comment: @StefanH The trailing comma is valid and makes future additions easier

Comment: @StefanH same apply to semicolon at the end of the type definition.

Comment: @lukas could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @StefanH `class Foo {};` <- it's optional in C#

Comment: @lukas That has nothing to do with object initializers - I didn't realize we had moved to the topic of all optional syntax in C#...

Comment: What is more notable is that the `;` is not optional after the collection initializer's `}`

Comment: @StefanH It's not all that notable: The collection initializer is a statement; a class declaration is not a statement.

Answer (score 94):

Note that the dictionary collection initialization `{ { key1, value1 }, { key2, value2 } }` depends on the Dictionary's `Add(TKey, TValue)` method.  You can't use this syntax with the list because it lacks that method, but you could make a subclass with the method:

```
public class KeyValueList<TKey, TValue> : List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new KeyValueList<string, string>
                   {
                       { "key1", "value1" },
                       { "key2", "value2" },
                       { "key3", "value3" },
                   };
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for describing exactly what the dictionary initializer sugar translates to.

Comment: You might want make that 'base.Add' because  as I understand C# you're simply calling the Add method of the `KeyValueList` object you've defined.

Comment: @RichardBarker you are correct that `base.Add` would be less ambiguous. I prefer as a matter of style to avoid `base.` and `this.` unless they are necessary, because in my view they just create so much clutter. But others disagree, and those people would indeed want to use the `base.` keyword.

Answer (score 15):

Another alternative that doesn't require making a subclass:

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> list = new Dictionary<String, String>
    {
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"},
    }.ToList();
```

As mentioned in the comments: drawbacks with this method include possible loss of ordering and inability to add duplicate keys.

Comment: hmm.. this might not preserve the ordering you have specified in your initializer, but i am not exactly sure. maybe you can initialize a sorted list and then convert ToList?

Comment: You also cannot store duplicate entries like this. One of the reasons for using List<KeyValuePair>...

Comment: It also involves hashing all the keys and a lot more allocations.

Answer (score 10):

Since collection initializers (C# 6.0) have not been mentioned here:

**Implementation**

```
public static class InitializerExtensions
{
   public static void Add<T1, T2>(this ICollection<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> target, T1 item1, T2 item2)
   {
       if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));

        target.Add(new KeyValuePair<T1, T2>(item1, item2));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { {"ele1item1", "ele1item2"}, { "ele2item1", "ele2item2" } };
```

**How to make it work**

Just include the right `using` statements in your file so that `InitializerExtensions` is available (meaning you could call `InitializerExtensions.Add` explicitly) and the special collection initializer syntax will become available if you are using VS 2015 or higher.

Comment: This extension must be a built-in part of C#, why we can use compact initilaizers for `Dictionary` but not `List` ?!

Answer (score -1):

Any initialization is done by `object(params_if_exist) { any public member or instance};`

f.e. `var list = new List<int> {1,2,3};`

`var bw = new BackgroundWorker() {WorkerSupportsCancellation = true};`

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.  The OP is looking for collection initialization specifically for KeyValue pairs.

Comment: i think that he must understand as it work, but not use ready solution, and ask again and again same question

Comment: Which "public member or instance" is set by `1,2,3` in your first example?

Comment: @phoog I think that it is syntactic sugar for grabbing the Add(T) method of the list, same applies with all collections, that's why digEmAll's solution works

Comment: @StefanH you are correct.  I was trying to point out *why* the answer "does not answer the OP's question", as you said, because "any public member or instance" is not an adequate description of initialization: it describes object initializers, but not collection initializers.