# How to initialize KeyValuePair object the proper way?

Tags: c#, initialization

I've seen in (amongst others) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694910/how-do-you-use-object-initializers-for-a-list-of-key-value-pairs) that people wonder how to initialize an instance of *KeyValuePair*, which expectedly should look like this.

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>
{ 
  Key = 1,
  Value = 2
};
```

It doesn't work, as if the properties aren't there. Intead, I need to use the constructor like this.

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2);
```

Admittedly shorter syntax but it bothers me that I can't use the initializer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 100):

You are not wrong you have to initialise a keyValuePair using

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2);
```

The reason that you cannot use the object initialisation syntax ie { Key = 1, Value = 2 } is because the Key and Value properties have no setters only getters (they are readonly).  So you cannot even do:

```
keyValuePair.Value = 1; // not allowed
```

Answer (score 30):

Dictionaries have compact initializers:

```
var imgFormats = new Dictionary<string, ChartImageFormat>()
{
    {".bmp", ChartImageFormat.Bmp}, 
    {".gif", ChartImageFormat.Gif}, 
    {".jpg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg}, 
    {".jpeg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg}, 
    {".png", ChartImageFormat.Png}, 
    {".tiff", ChartImageFormat.Tiff}, 
};
```

In this case the dictionary i used to associate file extensions with image format constants of chart objects.

A single keyvaluepair can be returned from the dictionary like this:

```
var pair = imgFormats.First(p => p.Key == ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 15):

`KeyValuePair<int, int>` is a struct, and, fortunately, it is *immutable* struct. In particular, this means that its properties are read only. So, you can't use object intializer for them.

Comment: +1 the 'struct' point is what explains it all. As you say, read only properties are just a consequence of KVP being a struct

Comment: @dennis it's an immutable struct because it's properties are read-only, not the other way round.

Comment: @Phil: I know this, thanks. The point is that KVP is a well-designed struct, because it is immutable. Of course, `struct` itself doesn't equal `immutability`.

Comment: @Phil of course, but this often leads to errors (like trying to update a property in a method just by passing the value and not the reference) Hence the good practice of making the properties read-only

Comment: Of course, this is exactly the same for an immutbale ***class***, for example the code `new Tuple<int, int> { Item1 = 1, Item2 = 2 }` gives the exact same error (together with an error that no constructor overload for `Tuple<,>` takes 0 arguments).

Comment: What is the advantage of that design? I'm assuming it's an intentional behavior.

Comment: @CRMconfusee Immutable **objects** are for code safety reasons.  Passing an object by value is passing the object's *reference* by value.  In other words, you can modify the object in the original thread after you pass it and affect the passed object.

Answer (score 15):

Ok you have the answers. As an alternative, I prefer factory pattern similar to `Tuple` class, for type inference magic :)

```
public static class KeyValuePair
{
    public static KeyValuePair<K, V> Create<K, V>(K key, V value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value);
    }
}
```

So short becomes shorter:

```
var keyValuePair = KeyValuePair.Create(1, 2);
```

Comment: Since 2017, this static method `Create` has been a part of .NET (but not .NET Framework), so you do not have to write the method yourself anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Here goes an example that does the job

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

The Key and Value properties have no setters. Thats why you can't use them in the initializer. Just use the constructor :) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I also prefer factory pattern. But I found this way much more to be more useful when I had to create a pair outside. This way I can support any simple to complex use case.

This way I could use any Type and make KeyValue Pairs from its properties or any predicate I want, But cleaner. Like the way similar to `IEnumerable.ToDictionary(keySelector,valueSelector)`

```cs
        public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> CreatePair<TSource, TKey, TValue>(
         this TSource source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, 
         Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
        {
            if (source is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (keySelector is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
            }

            if (valueSelector is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueSelector));
            }

            return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(
                         keySelector.Invoke(source), 
                         valueSelector.Invoke(source));
        }
```

And you use.

```cs
yourObject.CreatePair(
        x=> x.yourKeyPropery, 
        x=> SomeOperationOnYourProperty(x.yourValueProperty));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224760%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms224761%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) properties are read-only, therefore you can't use them in an object initializer.

See this entry in the [C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing something wrong. The KeyValuePairs properties are read-only. You cannot set them. Additionally, there is no empty default constructor. You need to use the constructor provided.

Comment: It is correct that there is no default constructor. However the code `var test = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();` will still be OK. The reason is that `KeyValuePair<,>` is a struct. And for a struct, the default value (also called `default(KeyValuePair<int, int>)`) will be created if you use a `new` object expression with zero arguments. In this case, a pair where both key and value are `default(int)` which is zero.

Comment: I believe that's incorrect. My IntelliSense tells me that I can create *new KeyValuePair()*, whatever that might be good for. Aren't all classes supposed to have a default empty constructor? Or was it in Java...?

Comment: @CRMconfusee no thats not a requirement for classes in C#, but for structs.