# Any way to add arrays into HTTP request URI by using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I want to send a HTTP request that looks like this:
`http://api.com/main?id=1234&id=5678`, the id will be GUID in string eventually.

I tried the below piece of code:

```
var idString = string.Join(",", listOfIds);

var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"id", idString}
};

requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(requestUri, queryString);
```

This will give me like: `http://api.com/main?id=1234,5678` but I want the style like above.

Is there anyway to achieve this without using for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a loop? `String.Join` itself uses a loop and a StringBuilder. You can also use `&id=` as the separator and prepend that with `id=`

Comment: Hmm ok let me try it~

Comment: Seriously, what's the question? Why not use a loop? Are you trying to avoid temporary strings? Don't want to write a function tot do the job?

Comment: The first id will have `?id=` instead of `&id=` so I'm not sure how can I use loops to achieve that..

Comment: Add it to the StringBuilder before starting the loop. `?` will be added by `AddQueryString` itself

Comment: I changed the separator to `&id=` but when it adds as query string it does not recognize it? The whole URI turns out like this `http://api.com/main?id=1234%26id%5678`.

Comment: You've already built the query string. You don't need `AddQueryString` any more

Comment: Which .NET Core version do you use? .NET Core 5 added the ability to work with arrays of values using [AddQueryString(String, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,String>>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.addquerystring?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebUtilities_QueryHelpers_AddQueryString_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_System_String_System_String___) and `AddQueryString(String, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,StringValues>>)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QueryHelpers doesn't work with arrays because there's no standard way to pass an array of values in a query string. Some applications accept `id=1,2,3` others `id=1&id=2&id=3` while others `id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3`.

**.NET (Core) 5 and later**

[AddQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.addquerystring?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebUtilities_QueryHelpers_AddQueryString_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_System_String_System_String___) now works with lists of `KeyValuePair<string,string>`or `KeyValuePair<string,StringValues>`

```
var parameters=new []{
                   new KeyValuePair<string,string>("id",new StringValues(arrayOfIds)),
                   new KeyValuePair<string,string>("other","value"),
                   ...
               };
var finalUri=QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(requestUri, parameters);
```

The [StringValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) constructors accept either a single string or an array of strings

**Before .NET (Core) 5**

`String.Join` itself [uses a loop and a StringBuilder](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,92) to create a new string without allocating temporary strings. Strings are immutable, so *any* string modification operation results in a new temporary string.

You could use [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,92) as a guide to build your own loop. A quick solution could be something like this:

```
string ArrayToQueryString_DONT_USE(string name,string[] values)
{
    var result=new StringBuilder();
    result.AppendFormat("{0}={1}",name,value);
    for(int i=1;i<values.Length;i++)
    {
        result.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}',name,values[i]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, that won't work if the parameter names or values need encoding. That's what [AddQueryString](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/QueryHelpers.cs#L92) does, using, once again, a StringBuilder to avoid allocating temporary strings. We can borrow that code as well:

```
string ArrayToQueryString(string name,string[] values)
{
    var result=new StringBuilder();
    result.AppendFormat("{0}={1}",name,value);
    for(int i=1;i<values.Length;i++)
    {
        result.Append('&');
        result.Append(UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(name));
        result.Append('=');
        result.Append(UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(values[i]));
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It gives me error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'

Comment: Heads up: Your syntax ...new KeyValuePair("other","value")... produces an error: "cannot create an instance of the static class...". See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495165/how-to-initialize-keyvaluepair-object-the-proper-way

Answer (score 0):

> This will give me like: http://api.com/main?id=1234,5678 but I want the style like above, e.g., http://api.com/main?id=1234&id=5678

I think the accept answer didn't address this issue from OP.

Using `AddQueryString(string uri, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryString)` overload when you have an array you want to be part of the query string would only give you the comma-separated string as the parameter, and most of the time that is not what you want.

For example,

```cs
var endpoint = "v1/api/endpoint";
var arrayOfIds = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var queryString = new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("id",new StringValues(arrayOfIds)),
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("other","value"),
    ...
};

var url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(endpoint, queryString);
```

The url at the end would look like ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LlFA1k))

```cs
v1/api/endpoint?id=1,2,3&other=value
```

To get what OP wants, we will need to use the StringValues' overload `AddQueryString(string uri, IEnumerable<KeyVaulePair<string, StringValues>> queryString)`.

For example,

```cs
var endpoint = "v1/api/endpoint";
var arrayOfIds = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var queryString = new []
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("id", new StringValues(arrayOfIds)),
    new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("other", "value")
};
        
var url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(endpoint, queryString);
```

Then the URL would look like ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QAWAur))

```cs
v1/api/endpoint?id=1&id=2&id=3&other=value
```

#### Bonus

Just in case you wonder why you don't see the StringValues' overload, even you are running on .NET 5+?

Maybe you have multiple versions of .NET installed, and your app is still referencing the old version 2.*, which is marked as deprecated recently.

To make sure you use the latest .NET, in your .csproj file, you can add the framework reference like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    ...
</Project>
```